# How to add an element to next open location in a string array in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have an array of length 10 and only has 2 to 3 elements in it at one time.  How do I add an element to the next open location in the array.  I'm new to VB.net so any code snippets would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real "next open location" because a `String()` is fixed sized. If you intialize it with a length of 10 you should fill it immediately. Otherwise there is no way to determine which "slot" is free. Note that in general even `Nothing` could be a valid value for a string.

I would suggest to use a [`List(Of String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) instead which supports [adding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) items.

If you can ensure that `Nothing` is never a possible value you can use [`Array.FindIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.findindex(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim firstEmptyIndex As Int32 = Array.FindIndex(strArray, Function(s) s Is Nothing)
If firstEmptyIndex >= 0 Then
    strArray(firstEmptyIndex) = "Foo"
End If
```

or with [`Array.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim firstEmptyIndex As Int32 = Array.IndexOf(strArray, Nothing)
```